# How to normalise audio after resampling

Tags: audio, normalize, resampling

I'm thinking of using [libsamplerate](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/index.html) to resample audio files which seems fairly simple.

In the [FAQ](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/faq.html#Q001) it states that after resampling that the audio should be normalised which I'm not sure how to do.

It states that the audio samples should be in the range (-1.0, 1.0).
Is it just a case of:

1. Finding the sample which lies the furthest from this range
2. Calculating the coefficient that will result in it's value being -1.0 or 1.0
3. Applying that coefficient to every sample in the audio file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes, you have to find the sample of largest absolute value, and just divide all samples by this value, which ensures all samples will lie in the (-1.0,1.0) range. Of course it requires you have access to the whole audio data in advance (you cannot normalize a stream, since you do not know what samples you will be getting, e.g 3 seconds into the future).

Keep in mind though that this operation will probably result in a change of perceived loudness ('volume'). If you want the overall loudness to be preserved after resampling, you have to measure it before and after resampling, and apply a proper coefficient.

Comment: How do you measure the audio loudness? As I will need  to preserve it.

Comment: Loudness is more a psycho-acoustic parameter, not a physical one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness), but anyway for your needs you may use the mean amplitude of the signal.